# Can anyone tell me how to convert PPT to PDF using node js? (with example)

Tags: pdf

Can anyone tell me how to convert PPT  to PDF using node js ?

I have ppt file, I want to convert in pdf format in my node js application

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Post the code snippets you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the convert utility of Libre Office. I believe there is no direct way to do that with a node.js plugin or library.